# Slow loading Magento 1.9 site with Ultimo theme and over 2K Categories

Tags: magento-1.9

Please take a look at my site: 162.252.104.196. It's very slow loading. I have the Magento Profiler turned on, but don't exactly know how to interpret these results. I think it's the fact that I am using the ULTIMO theme and a mega menu for left navigation. And we have over 2K Categories, but have only loaded about 200 products. I switched back over to the default template and the pages still loaded slow. Any ideas how to debug?

THANKS!

EDIT:

Some lines of the profiler on a product page:

```
Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
mage    5.4082  1   0   0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Category 0.4044  10911   8,473,712   1,572,864
DISPATCH EVENT:model_load_before    0.0354  9059    436,400 0
frontend/ultimo/campbell/template/page/2columns-left.phtml  5.2482  1   12,619,296  13,369,344
frontend/ultimo/campbell/template/page/html/header.phtml    5.1529  1   10,999,792  11,796,480
frontend/ultimo/campbell/template/infortis/ultramegamenu/mainmenu.phtml 5.1254  1   9,016,176   9,699,328
frontend/ultimo/campbell/template/page/html/left_breadcrumb.phtml   0.0659  1   42,072  262,144
```

Comment: Install package aoe_profiler. It will make interpreting the profiler results meaningful

Comment: Do you have flat catalog and products enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The theme or some of the modules you have installed have used some very bad programming patterns.

It loads 9048 times a category model from the database.

Also I assume the left Navigation bar is responsible, as the template frontend/ultimo/campbell/template/page/2columns-left.phtml needs 5.2 seconds, from the 6.2 of the whole product page.

But Iam not experianced in reading the default magento profiler output, I may misinterprete some parts